# Is it safe to remove 2 "extra" jack studs to make a 60" wide door opening wider?

Tags: doors, framing, studs, removal

We went to install our new main entrance 60" door (replacing double-door with single door and 2 sidelights).  After we received the new door and shaved out more of the sheet rock, we saw that there were 2 jack studs on EACH side supporting the header (so a total of 4 jack studs).  To fit the door in, we would have to remove 1 jack stud on each side of the header.

The door "expert" where we ordered the door from said that he had never seen an extra jack stud on either side and that they were probably put there, at some time, to accommodate the installation of the current (smaller door).  He thought it would be OK to remove them.  The carpenter said he would put a metal corner bracket to ensure stability and load transfer from the header to the a single jack stud on each side.

Does this plan sound like it would compromise the structural integrity of the framing?

Comment: Can you add a photo that shows the header and stud configuration on one or both sides?  If you are not able to actually post the picture then upload the picture(s) to http://imgur.com and then include the URL in to your question and someone will help to embed your picture.

Answer (score 1):

The use of two jack studs under each end of the header could have been done for any number of reasons.

1. If the header supports a lot of weight from above it may have been
   deemed desirable to have the extra support on each end.
2. If the header has an long span it is sometimes desirable to add
   additional support for the header.
3. As you suggested it is possible that the rough opening was
   originally made wider than needed for the door that was actually
   installed.
4. The original contractor may have wanted there to be extra wide solid
   wall support at each side of the opening than the normal 3" offered
   by just one stud + jack stud. It is not at all uncommon to do this
   for large window openings in professional construction where it is
   known that drapery hardware will mount beyond the width of any
   window casings.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking up to 72" opening only a single jack stud is required.  If there was a point load over the door the contractor may have added the extra support.  Other wise - code does not require double.